# How to find a record from more than one table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two table containing some information as below
ENRNO, PROGRAM, NAME, ADDRESS, AGE

I want to find data referencing ENRNO which is containing from one of the given table but I don't know which table have the information.

Please suggest.

Malay Barik

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: And table definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ENRNO is unique in tables u may try use UNION

```
select * from t1 
where ENRNO ='ENRNO1'
UNION select * from t2 
where ENRNO ='ENRNO1'
```

else use DISTINCT and subquery

```
select DISTINCT * from (
select * from t1 
where ENRNO ='ENRNO1'
UNION select * from t2 
where ENRNO ='ENRNO1')
```

But goodest way for solving this is redesign(normalize) you DB.

Comment: Sorry it is not only two table it is 8 tables. please suggest how to get data 
Андрей Ганин

Comment: using UNION for 8 tables.

Comment: I was input these command and found working well but this is too long, is there any shortcut of this formula,please inform Андрей Ганин: select ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN07
where ENRNO =ENRNO1
UNION SELECT ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN08 
where ENRNO =ENRNO1
UNION SELECT ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN09
where ENRNO =ENRNO1
UNION SELECT ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN10
where ENRNO =ENRNO1
UNION SELECT ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN11
where ENRNO =ENRNO1
UNION SELECT ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN12
where ENRNO =ENRNO1
UNION SELECT ENRNO, NAME, PROGRAM from FRJAN13
where ENRNO =ENRNO1